# Why does this logic statement seem to not work?

Tags: python

I am writing a basic Vernam encryption cypher however it is only working for specific characters.

```
def binary(char: str):
    val = ord(char)
    return list(format(val, 'b').zfill(8))


def vernam(text: str, cipher: str):
    # this first portion just repeats the cipher text as until it is the same length as the text to      
    # be encrypted in my trials I was using 'hello' and 'hi' so it converted to 'hihih'
    text_chars = list(text)
    cipher_chars = list(cipher)
    encrypt_chars = []
    while len(cipher_chars) < len(text_chars):
        for i in range(len(list(cipher))):
            cipher_chars.append(list(cipher)[i])
    while len(cipher_chars) > len(text_chars):
        cipher_chars.pop()
    bin_encrypt = []
    for i in range(len(text_chars)):
        bin_text = binary(text_chars[i])
        bin_cipher = binary(cipher_chars[i])
        bin_encrypt.append([])
        for j in range(8):
            print(bin_text[j], bin_cipher[j])
            # XOR Logic gate.
            if (bin_text[j] != bin_cipher[j]) and ((bin_text[j] or bin_cipher[j]) == "1"):
                bin_encrypt[i].append("1")
            else:
                bin_encrypt[i].append("0")
        for i in range(len(bin_encrypt)):
        encrypt_chars.append(int(''.join(bin_encrypt[i]), 2))
    print(encrypt_chars)
```

The error, I believe, occurs within the XOR when bin_text is 0 and bin_cipher[j] is 1, this should output a 1, (as tested by just doing that line with those values) but it instead is outputting a 0 and I am unsure why.

I tried with the text of 'hello' and the cipher of 'hi', based on the binary XOR performed by hand I expected to get: the characters of the unicode: 0,12,4,5,7
But instead get the unicode: 0, 4, 4, 4, 7

Comment: `(bin_text[j] or bin_cipher[j]) == "1"` is not equivalent to `bin_text[j] == "1" or bin_cipher[j] == "1"`

Comment: I think you might want `"1" in [bin_text[j], bin_cipher[j]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JohnColeman has pointed out, the problem is that the `(bin_text[j] or bin_cipher[j]) == "1"` does not return what you expect it to return. The parentheses in this expression make Python compare the expression `bin_text[j] or bin_cipher[j]` to the string `"1"`.
This is one of the many cases when Python's syntax does not follow natural language syntax, and it can be confusing at times. To fix this, replace the faulty statement with `bin_text[j] == "1" or bin_cipher[j] == "1"`.